# Is it correct to say "I had a friend visiting me in my dream"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it correct to say "I had a friend visiting me in my dream"? If it is, what is the difference between this phrase and this one - "A friend visited me in my dream"? I understand that I can use "I saw a friend in my dream" or any other similar phrase, but I was just wondering if it is possible to use this one. 
Thank you!

Comment: It is correct, in the right context.  And context determines whether it is better than the alternative you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatically possible. The first suggests to me that the friend's visit was quite long, probably persisting throughout the dream. Without the context of the dream, if you said, "I had a friend visiting me [...] I'd probably expect you to continue the sentence with "when [such and such] happened." In other words the friend's visit would be a sort of continuing background to other events. The second sentence, in my opinion, implies nothing about the duration of the visit.

Comment: Thank you so much for you detailed answer! You helped me a lot :)